# Checking that a set is a finitely generated ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, noetherian, finitely-generated

The exercise asks us to prove that $I = \{ f \in \Bbb R[X,Y,Z] \mid f(a,b,c) = 0, ~\forall\,(a,b,c)\in \Bbb S^2 \}$ is a finitely generated ideal of $\Bbb R[X,Y,Z]$.

Well, clearly $I$ is an ideal of $\Bbb R[X,Y,Z]$. Since $\Bbb R$ is Noetherian, by Hilbert's basis theorem, $\Bbb R[X,Y,Z]$ is also Noetherian, and hence $I$ is finitely generated.

I don't know if I am being paranoid (I'll just delete the question if this is the case), but that was all [*too easy*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGAu_DeKckI). Can you check if I am missing something obvious here?

Comment: Looks good to me, and I would accept that as an answer, but they probably wanted you to find explicit generator(s).

Comment: That's reassuring, thanks. The exercise really doesn't say anything about generators. Maybe I'll try to find one just for the kicks. I think that $p(X,Y,Z) = -1 + X^2+Y^2+Z^2$ looks promising, though.

Comment: That’s what I would have thought. Even that is too too simple.

Comment: Unless I'm missing some neat trick, proving that $-1+X^2+Y^2+Z^2$ generates $I$ is going to be quite hard (at least, without using some machinery from algebraic geometry).